# Usage of RemoteChunkingManagerStepBuilderFactory and RemoteChunkingWorkerBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-batch, integration, chunking

Has anyone tried using the remote chunking classes introduced from Spring 4.1? As per the spring documentation it eradicated the explicit use of channelItemWriter for master and ChunkProcessor for slave config. I have an XML defined config for master where a job is configured with multiple steps using spring batch. Also, a faultTolerantChunkProcessor is defined as a chunk processor for a chunk handler in slave.

However, my messages are not being pushed to ibm mq. I have written the corresponding spring 4.1 classes using java dsl. Can some one suggest me a good approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete example that uses these APIs here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/remotechunking.

The sample can be executed with this test: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/RemoteChunkingJobFunctionalTests.java which is passing. The sample uses an embedded ActiveMQ broker, but should work with any other broker.